# I get a framelayout error I can't add an image

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

I want to show an image into my Android application.

As you can see I put an `ImageView` into my layout and reference it with `android:src="@drawable/android"`

The picture path is `MyApp6/app/src/main/res/drawable/android/a.jpeg`, which I'm sure it's correct.

However, after building the project I get this **error message**:

```
No resuorce found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value @drawable/android.")
```

I don't have a computer so I use aide.

Here is my XML layout

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#fff000"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tw2"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:text="Güzel Sözler"
            android:shadowColor="#00ccff"
            android:shadowRadius="2"
            android:shadowDx="1"
            android:shadowDy="1"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tw1"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:text=""
            android:shadowColor="#00ccff"
            android:shadowRadius="2"
            android:shadowDx="1"
            android:shadowDy="1"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        
        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/btn1"
            android:text="random"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:background="#cae1ff"
            android:textColor="#ff3030"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            
        <FrameLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:context=".MainActivity">
        
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/android"/>
        
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
                android:text="Android Programlama"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>
        
        </FrameLayout>
    
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: First of all you need to make sure that you have added the image a.jpeg in your drawable folder. If you have added it correctly then to access the image you don't have to use `@drawable/android`, instead use `@drawable/a` since the name of the image file is a.jpeg, not android.jpeg.

Comment: Unfortunately, the same error continues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're adding your images with file explorer. Don't create subfolder. If you want to add your images with file explorer use this path:

```
MyApp6/app/src/main/res/drawable/a.jpeg
```

instead of:

```
MyApp6/app/src/main/res/drawable/android/a.jpeg
```

Or you can copy your image and paste it (or drag and drop) in to drawable resource folder directly on Android Studio software. Both will put your image in to same path.

After that set your image to your ImageView.

```
android:src="@drawable/a"
```

Comment: So how do I print in the middle of the picture? and I'll set a new picture. What size should the picture be for full screen?

Comment: What you mean with "print in the middle of the picture"?.About your other question, if you want a fullscreen image you can set ImageView's width and height attribute as match_parent (as you already set)  but in your layout you already have another Views so your ImageView can't be fullscreen.

Comment: https://i.resimyukle.xyz/NeT7VS.jpg I want to make full screen.    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
  android:src="@drawable/a"
  />

Comment: I think you want your image as background. If so you don't need to use ImageView. You can set your image as a LinearLayout's background. Your LinearLayout's background is: android:background="#fff000" change it like     android:background="@drawable/a" and your image will be set as a background

Comment: Or if you still want to use ImageView and image as a fullscreen without setting your image as a background, you can change your parent layout as ConstraintLayout and set ImageView's constraints.

Comment: Thanks :) 
   I took care of it thanks to you

Comment: It looks like you set background 2 times. Remove this one: android:background="#fff000"

Comment: yes i noticed it later so how can i put the button to the bottom left :)

Comment: Knk sen Türksun instagram versene :)))

Comment: Bosuna ceviri kullaniyom

Comment: Hesap var ama kullanmıyorum. Bu arada bu layout ile istediğini yapman biraz zor.

Comment: Anladm peki nasıl yapacağım iki buton eklicem biri sag alt biri sol alt

Comment: Hesabı buldum toygur_kutlu ekle yaz ama dediğim gibi normalde kullanmıyorum o yüzden mesaj gelirse haberim olmuyor. Şimdi haberim olduğu için cevap verebilirim.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using:

```
android:src="@drawable/android"
```

use:

```
android:src="@drawable/a"
```

This is because your path is `MyApp6/app/src/main/res/drawable/android/a.jpeg`
and you were putting the name of the folder before instead of the actual image.

Comment: Try Cleaning Project, Rebuilding Project, Clearing Caches/ Restarting.